# Downloading speed limitation in MVC.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have MVC.NET 2.0 project. It allows clients to download files which are stored on server. I use FileContentResult class for these purposes. How do I can add limitation of maximum downloading speed for unregistered users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not automagic way to accomplish this. You will have to take control of the response stream and throttle it. As a quick example, you can look at this URI (notice it is not necessarily THE answer to your problem, but an example):
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Bandwidth_throttling.aspx

Translated, this means is you are not going to solve this through MVC alone.

Comment: I'm going to use such custom stream in a bunch with FileStreamResult class.

Answer (score 3):

This is something you would probably want to accomplish using [IIS's Bit Rate Throttling](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/148/bit-rate-throttling-configuration-walkthrough/) rather than coding it yourself. No need to re-invent the wheel. IIS is also more flexible, easy to change on the fly, and is robust.